# find the matching word C#

Tags: c#, regex, substring, string-matching

```
http://www.vkeong.com/2008/food-drink/nasi-lemak-wai-sik-kai-kepong-baru/
```

Hi, how to get the `'nasi-lemak-wai-sik-kai-kepong-baru'` from this hyperlink using C#?

Thanks.

Comment: This gets you what you want: string result = "nasi-lemak-wai-sik-kai-kepong-baru" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about;

```
var uri = new System.Uri("http://www.vkeong.com/2008/food-drink/nasi-lemak-wai-sik-kai-kepong-baru/");
string dir = new System.IO.FileInfo(uri.LocalPath).Directory.Name;
```

(This would return `2008` were there no terminating `/`)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Segments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments.aspx) property of the URI class

```
URI uri = new URI("http://www.example.com/alpha/beta/gamma");

foreach(string s in uri.Segments)
{
  Console.Writeline(s);
}
```

Comment: Nice! This is a much better answer than mine. Can you please post some code for the OP though... There seems to be an issue with the trailing / though

Answer (score 0):

For that specific string I'd use the `String.Substring(int offset, int length)` method.

```
url.Substring(38, 14);
```

Comment: You're probably right, but that is how he phrased the question.

Answer (score 0):

Trim the last /, then find the index of the now last / and make a substring from this found idnex to the end.